# reload table datatables with fragment

Tags: html, ajax, spring-boot, datatables, thymeleaf

i m trying to reload a fragment by ajax, but when i reload my event select does not work neither the row count, it means the default config is not working as i want:

```
        @PostMapping("/admin/add") 
        public String add(@ModelAttribute(name = "client") Client client,Model model){

        client.setPassword("sdfsdf");
        client.setPoints(2);
        clientServiceImpl.addOne(client);

        return "clients :: resultsList";


}
```

and this is my js file:

```
    /*start method*/
          var rowBodyClient = document.getElementById('rowBodyClient');

          // Use Ajax to submit form data
          var url = "/admin/clients/add"; // El script a dónde se realizará la petición.
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $("#form-client").serialize(), // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data != null)
                    {

                    console.log(data);  
                    rowBodyClient.innerHTML = data;
                    table.draw();

                    }else{


                    $("#snackbar").text("Hubo un error al ingresar el cliente");
                    $("#snackbar").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                    $("#snackbar").addClass("show");


                    setTimeout(function(){ $("#snackbar").removeClass("show"); }, 3000);

                    $('#form-client').parsley().reset();


                  }    

                }

          });
```

[image]
i had replace the tbody, but it works but the datatables doest relaod correctly

[image]

Comment: You simply cannot manipulate a DOM element and expect DataTables to figure that out and work with whatever changes you have made. How should that happen? Look at the documentation, for example `rows.add` ...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in the past and i solved it with the next manner.
"dt-opt" is the id of the table. This code is inside of the success function of the ajax. This code send a request to the server to load a specific fragment

```
$("#dt-opt").load('?loadFragment=true');
```

And this one, it's to load the table.

```
@GetMapping(value = {"", "/"})
public ModelAndView showStudios(ServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(name = "loadFragment", required = false) Boolean loadFragment) {

    List<StudioDto> l = studioService.listForCurrentOwner();

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("studios", l);

    if (loadFragment != null && loadFragment) {
        //Loads the fragment named studiosList on studios view
        modelAndView.setViewName(VIEW_PATH + "/studios :: studiosTable");
    } else {
        //Loads all the view
        modelAndView.setViewName(VIEW_PATH + "/studios");
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Send me a personal message and i can help you.